# Error building Ada Web Server (AWS) on macOS Sierra

Tags: ada, gnat

I have updated my gnat to the latest version from AdaCore and trying to rebuild the latest AWS (Ada Web Server) also downloaded from AdaCore. I got some errors when building:

```
   aws-services-web_block-context.ads:106:21: argument of pragma "SUPPRESS" is not valid check name
aws-services-web_block-context.ads:106:21: argument of pragma "SUPPRESS" is not valid check name

   compilation of aws-services-web_block-context.adb failed
   compilation of aws-services-web_block-registry.adb failed

gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
make: *** [build-native] Error 4
```

What could have been wrong? Or, have I overlook something?

Thanks.
Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check that is invalid is `Tampering_Check`, which is to do with the resource-intensive ARM-specified checks on improper use of Containers (basically, is one part of the code trying to change the structure of a Container that another is already using?)

I don’t know why you’ve had this problem: both GNAT GPL 2016 and FSF GCC 6.1.0 are OK with the pragma. Are you sure you’re using the latest compiler?

One other thing to watch out for is that the *master* branch at [Github](https://github.com/AdaCore/aws) may rely on compiler features not available in compiler releases available to unsupported customers; if using GNAT GPL 2016, maybe the *gpl-2016* branch would be safer, if not up to date.

Comment: You are right Simon. My bad. I mixed up the version of gnat in two separate folders and I was actually using the old one. I deleted both and reinstalled gnat and rebuilt AWS. It works now.